# Printer Not Installing by hp-lip?

Tags: printing, printer, hplip, hp-printer

So I have a hp - Laser Jet 4050

I Installed Linux Mint 19 a week ago ,

so I wanted to install it

I run hp-setup in terminal

[image]

with this setup

[image]

I click Usb and this is what appears

[image]

and this on terminal

[image]

This is strange because when I enter lsusb in terminal this comes ,(Device 014 is the printer , i figured that out when i typed lsusb without connecting printer and it was'nt appearing )

[image]

Can anyone tell why is it not detecting my printer , 
Btw my printer is very old and it has a parallel(connected to printer ) to  usb adapter (connected to computer) ..

EDIT....

I just typed hp-check i  in terminal , what do i do now? :/ :(

this returned

[image]

Answer (score 0):

QinHeng Electronics CH340S is a serial/parallel port adapter, not the printer itself. And it looks like Linux has a driver for that adapter chip (the module name should be `ch341`), but only for its serial port adapter mode. And using a serial port with that kind of printer would be agonizingly slow.

With a supported USB->parallel port adapter, you would select "Parallel port (LPT)" in the Device Discovery window, and then, if necessary, type in the device name. It might be something like `/dev/usb/lp0`; I haven't had a chance to actually use a USB->parallel port adapter with Linux, so I don't know for sure.

But if the printer is HP LaserJet 4050, it should have a network interface as standard. Connect it to your network and then choose "Network/Ethernet/Wireless" from that Device Discovery window, and it might even auto-detect the printer if it's present in the local network segment. If it does not auto-detect, get a network configuration settings printout using the printer's control panel and verify the network settings. If it has old settings from the place it was previously used in, Google for "LaserJet 4050 cold reset".

Comment: Selecting parallel port (lpt) , gives message in terminal "error: No devices found on bus: par"